# SQL count distinct or not null for each column for many columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to analyze a large table with hundreds of columns. A lot of columns are unused.

To investigate I could do something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column1 
FROM myTable
```

or

```
WITH C AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Column1
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM C
```

Then I do the same for column2 and so on. However these queries only work for one column which is time consuming and does not give overview in one glance.

Any idea how to build such investigation query for all columns in one?

Answer (score 3):

You need only 1 query where you have to list all the columns of the table:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Column1) column1_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT Column2) column2_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT Column3) column3_count
       .....................................
FROM MyTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

For local purposes only, you can make it dynamic like this:

Get the columns of the table
the query is created as the colleagues did and then it is executed with the EXEC()

```
DECLARE @columns as Table(RowId INT IDENTITY(1,1), ColumnName nVarchar(50))
DECLARE @ii int = 0
DECLARE @max int = 0

DECLARE @sqlQuery nVarchar(MAX)

INSERT INTO @columns
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Customer'

SET @sqlQuery = 'SELECT '

SELECT @max = COUNT(*) FROM @columns

WHILE @ii <= @max
BEGIN
    
    SELECT @sqlQuery = CONCAT(@sqlQuery,'COUNT(DISTINCT ',ColumnName,') ',LOWER(ColumnName),'_count, ')
      FROM @columns
     WHERE RowId = @ii
    SET @ii = @ii + 1
END

SELECT @sqlQuery = CONCAT(@sqlQuery,'FROM Customer')
SELECT @sqlQuery = REPLACE(@sqlQuery,', FROM',' FROM')
select @sqlQuery

EXEC (@sqlQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should flesh out your requirement a bit more.  If all you want to know is if a column contains only NULLs, you'll want to check for `max(ColumnName) is null`

```
declare @sql table (id int identity(1,1), QueryString nvarchar(max))
create table ##emptyColumns (emptyColumn nvarchar(128))
declare @i int = 0
declare @iMax int
declare @runthis nvarchar(max)

insert @sql

select 'select ''' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + quotename(c.name) + ''' as ''column'' 
from ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + ' 
having max(' + c.name + ') is null'

from sys.sysobjects o
  inner join sys.syscolumns c on c.id = o.id
  inner join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = o.uid

where o.type = 'U'

order by s.name
, o.name
, c.colorder

select @iMax = count(*)
from @sql
print @iMax

while @i < @iMax
begin
  set @i = @i + 1
  
  select @runthis = 'insert into ##emptyColumns 
  ' + QueryString
  from @sql
  where id = @i
  
  execute sp_executesql @runthis
end

select *
from ##emptyColumns

drop table ##emptyColumns
```

Answer (score 0):

One further option you might consider:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

select @sql = isnull(@sql + ' union all ', '') + 'select ''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''', 
  sum(case when ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' is null then 1 else 0 end) as null_values,
  count(distinct ' + COLUMN_NAME + ') as count_distinct
from ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ' 
'
from information_schema.columns 
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MySchema' and TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'

exec (@sql)
```

If you had very big tables with large numbers of columns and were only interested in empty columns you could look into something like checksum_agg(checksum(column_name)). It may help improve performance.

You'd need to be wary of column data types, as they are not all compatible with distinct.